# Pandas Dataframe, looking for way to speed up df.apply that uses math

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I am using a Pandas Dataframe that has 29M rows.  I am doing a computation based on four columns which are all floats.

This call is taking over 1100 seconds:

```
df['d_from_avg'] = df.apply(lambda row: \
    math.sqrt((row.x - row.avg_x)**2 + (row.y - row.avg_y)**2),axis=1)
```

Would anyone have any suggestions for speeding this up?  Is there a better option than using an apply in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the vectorized operations instead of calculating row by row.

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
np.sqrt((df['x'] - df['avg_x'])**2 + (df['y'] - df['avg_y'])**2)
```

It will be much faster than apply (tried it on a dataframe with 1000 rows):

```
%timeit t = np.sqrt((df['x'] - df['avg_x'])**2 + (df['y'] - df['avg_y'])**2) 
1000 loops, best of 3: 280 µs per loop

%timeit t = df.apply(lambda row: \
    math.sqrt((row.x - row.avg_x)**2 + (row.y - row.avg_y)**2),axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 40.5 ms per loop
```

Comment: That did it!  Thanks very much!